# How to import a java class i created in jython and call a method

Tags: java, python, jython

I have made a java class that calls other java classes and then prints to a screen. i am trying to build a python interface that calls my java class, runs the one method within it, and terminates. i cannot get access to my method. i have used the line "import directory.directory2.myClass.java (and .jar and .class) i made the .jar file from both the raw code and from the .class file. none of these seem to be working. i set sys.path.append to point to the directory where the java files are. Do i need to convert my java class file to a python module? and if so how do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jython supports loading Java classes as if they were Python modules. It searches the directories in `sys.path` for `.class` files.

**First, make sure your Java class has already been compiled with `javac`**.

Then, do a `sys.path.append(d)`, where `d` is the directory containing the package. So if your class says `package foo.bar;` at the top, and resides at `mydir/foo/bar/myclass.java`, then you must have `mydir` in `sys.path` (**NOT** one of the subdirs of `mydir`).

Finally, import the class via something like `from foo.bar import myclass`. The names between must match up between Python and Java! You'll be doing "from [package] import [class]".

Comment: it still is saying no module named directory.directory2, i made sure the path was set to the directory where i have my jython file, i even tried both with and without the sys.path.append. it wont find the directory

Comment: You must, as I said, set `sys.path` to contain **the folder which holds** `directory`. You also have to make sure that `myClass` is in `package directory.directory2`.

Comment: Does this somehow not work if the package happens to start with `com.`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
from directory.directory2 import myClass
myObject = myClass()
myObject.myMethod()
```

Comment: is that the .java file .class file or a .py file

Comment: i am also getting an error saying "from directory.directory2 import myClass" ImportError: no module named directory.directory2

Comment: that is the .py file you should have myClass in the CLASSPATH

Comment: i do not follow. i set sys.path.append to point to where the java classes are. myClass is a .java file. how do i then make that into a .py file to be called by my main python program

Comment: you have to your .java compiled with javac as said Borealid